# What service accounts to use when installing SQL Server 2008 on a Dev Box

Tags: sql-server

I am installing SQL Server 2008 on my development machine and during the install I am asked to assign accounts to the different services. What account should I use for the services where no user has been assigned if this is a simple development machine?

- Can I use the account I am logged in with (I am the only user on this machine)?
- Should I use the NT AUTHORITY/SYSTEM account?
- Can I user either or of the above or is there a downside to one or the other or should I use something totally different?

Comment: For more information about best practices you can get it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143504(v=sql.100).aspx

Answer (score 17):

You cannot use `NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE`. Also you cannot use a local account.

The recommended way is to use a domain account. Next best thing is `NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE`.

Comment: Yes you can. My local instance of SQL 2008 is running as Local System.

Comment: If you use a local account then your SQL server will not be accessible from any other machines.

Comment: @ERIC dear lord if you are running as Local System you have MORE privileges than Administrator.  Not really a good thing...

Answer (score 5):

I prefer to make a dedicated local account for SQL Services with no special rights, then let the SQL Server installer grant only the necessary perms to that account. It feels safer.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a dev machine, I generally just go with SYSTEM. Otherwise, I try to use a domain account, since I often need to kick off SSIS packages with SQL Server Agent, and it's nice if I can just use that service account instead of creating the proxies necessary.

Comment: My computer is not joined to a domain, only a workgroup. Would a domain account be the account I log into the computer in this case?

Comment: @Goodlife: Your domain is then your local computer, so yes, yes it would.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not on a domain, then you can use a local user account, and you can use still access from another machine.  You just have to match the username and password (that `domain` or `machine` part doesn't matter.

example:
`devmachine\Andy`
`homemachine\Andy`

Andy can access his devmachine from his homemachine.  At least, the user authentication will pass. Good luck setting up the firewall, ports, and the like.

Answer (score 0):

Only use a domain account if you need your SQL Server instance to communicate with other instances, Exchange or any other network services.  Otherwise just create a dedicated local system account.