# SQL Server installation / configuration error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

[image]

When I am installing SQL Server 2008 I get this error:

> TITLE: SQL Server 2008 Setup
>
> There are validation errors on this page. Click OK to close this dialog box. Review errors at the bottom Setup page, then provide valid parameters or click Help for more information.

Here, the account name I had selected it by going in Browse -> Advanced -> Find Now option.

When I login my window I have no any password option, it starts automatically. For this reason I don't provide any password here.

How can I fix it ??

Sorry and thanks in advance.

Comment: Joy Does laptop\joy have admin right ? if not then right click on the software (run.exe) then run as administrator. Try that

Comment: On a side note: it's 2015 and support ended for SQL Server 2008 over a year ago, since then three newer versions has been released so maybe it's time to move on to a newer version (if that is an option). The current version is 2014 sp 1.

Comment: Typically, I use "Network Service" or Local System unless I need some other permission for the server. This (http://stackoverflow.com/q/1272670/16391) is not necessarily a duplicate, but has some additional information on the subject.

Comment: No its not working, same problem has been occurred. @Hiten004

Comment: Thanks @StingyJack... your link has been  worked fine for me

Comment: Thanks everyone for responding and co-operating .

Answer (score 2):

The recommended way is to use a domain account. Next best thing is NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE.

[[What service accounts to use when installing SQL Server 2008 on a Dev Box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272670/what-service-accounts-to-use-when-installing-sql-server-2008-on-a-dev-box][1])

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall sql server completely by going into control panel,uninstall a program.
Delete folder “Microsoft SQL Server” from c:\Program Files.
Delete folder c:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Application Data\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server.
run regedit.exe (Start->Run), and delete key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

I too faced the same issue, Simple Solution..
Just check for the administrator account in Windows,
Run "net user" in CMD(as administrator)
look for Administrator User and you(as another user)
and then just select that for the Account Name Column. Worked for me.

Explanation: your logged in user, is not the admin account , its different but , i guess SQL requires admin rights, and hence requires Administrator account